# XeLaTeX extremely slow on mac

Tags: xetex

I used the same file, compiled well in a different old mac. Now, I have a fresh installment of MacTex on a brand new mac, but my xelatex is very slow, not even compiling.

All fonts are in system folders, not in user folder.

I've used xelatex and lualatex in different macs before.

Compilation gets stuck here:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
Process aborted
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,numbering=fraction,block=fill]{metropolis}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}{test}
    
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This compiles in my other computer for some weird reason but not on the fresh mactex I installed.

Any help?

Comment: Does Font Book show your selected fonts? Are you setting your fonts by font name or file name?

Comment: I am using it with a beamer theme that uses its own fonts I think. I am not selecting or setting any font separately. Also I added a MWE.

Comment: Fresh installation may take few hours to place all the necessary files in default location just you continue the work, speed will increase within 4-5 hrs

Comment: I installed it last week, it was just yesterday I needed xelatex and lualatex

Comment: When you did your first compilation?

Comment: with pdflatex last week, with xelatex I tried yesterday. still not working

Comment: Why is there both fontspec and fontenc? I think your example isn't complete. Have you updated the distribution since installation? Many packages have had updates since the release of TeX Live 2020 (which is installed by MacTeX-2020).

Comment: I don't know why there is both fontspec and fontenc. I think my example is complete -- notice that it is a beamer file with metropolis theme. I believe the theme is calling these packages. And I don't receive any missing packages notifications. And yes, before posting here I had updated my MacTex2020.

Comment: Have you updated your TeX Live distribution since installation?

Comment: And yes, before posting here I had updated my MacTex2020.

Comment: I figured it out. I deleted the texmf folder in my Library folder, and if got fixed.